# Is there a way to auto-increment in MYSQL after deleting a row from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to auto-increment in MYSQL after deleting a row from the database?

For example:
There is a table with 3 columns: StudentID, Student Name, and Contact details. Here StudentID will be the primary key which will keep incrementing after adding values in each column.

The PHP code will look as follows:

```
<?php


require_once "Delete_Form.php";
    
    if ($_GET || id['id']) {
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['id']);
    } else {
        echo 'Value was not brought over';
    }

 echo $id;
        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT StudentID, StudentName, Contact FROM student WHERE 
            StudentID='$id'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);


        $sql= "DELETE FROM `student` WHERE `student`.`studentID` = $id";
        echo "<pre>\n$sql\n</pre>\n";
        mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        echo 'Success -<a href="index.php">Continue...</a>';
        return;
```

Once we delete an entry from the database the Auto-Incrementation of StudentID will mess up i.e if the last entry had a StudentID of 12 and then we delete the same then the next row we enter will have StudentID of 13.

We can always do `` ALTER TABLE `student` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 `` which will reset it but that will solve the problem temporarily only.

Is there a way to add a PHP statement in the above code to reset auto increment whenever we delete a row?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225160/discussion-on-question-by-atharva-gaikwad-is-there-a-way-to-auto-increment-in-my).

Answer (score 0):

Do it never.

Primary key in a table identifies the row uniquely during the whole table lifetime. Pay attention - TABLE lifetime, not ROW lifetime. The fact that the row was deleted changes nothing - the value identifies this deleted row nevertheless.

If you need rows enumeration without the gaps then create special column for this purposes or enumerate in a query.

PS. By the way, synthetic AI PK must be hidden for the user at all - this column destination is row identifying and foreign keys subsystem work. It must not have any additional meaning.

Comment: Hmm, I guess there is a lot more to learn before asking questions. Thank you for helping me out with it